# Where does the git flow release message go?

Tags: git, gitflow

When creating a release with git flow like:

```
git flow release finish <branch_name>
```

I'm prompted for a release message. I grepped around to see where this go, but no succes. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stored as a tag message.

```
git show <tag>
```

reveals the message.

Internally the tag is stored in `.git/refs/tags/<tag>`. The content of the `<tag>` file is a hash e.g. `b04be91f81ead931b81eb6db72b4ec1179d27d8a`. This hash points to a zlib compressed packfile (which is why you couldn't find it via `grep`), which is stored in `.git/objects/b0/4be91f81ead931b81eb6db72b4ec1179d27d8a`. To show the contents of the file, you can use

```
git cat-file -p b04be91f81ead931b81eb6db72b4ec1179d27d8a
```